# No Share Links on Posts From My App

Tags: facebook, share, feed

Facebook posts coming from my application do not have share links. If I post the same link using "Update Status" at the top of the news feed, the share links appear as normal. Is this something wrong I am doing when posting to the user's feed.

Here is the URL that I am trying to post:
https://ficture.it/p/user/178/public/slice/D783vYTeAR4YmjEjE7CMHh...RlOOgTeER4YbqEjE7CMHh

Here is what it looks like in the news feed:
[image]

Comment: This happens for me, too.  One interesting thing is that it works fine (the "share" link is present) when the story is just text.  When the story is more than just text - if it includes a photo, video, or link, for example - then the "share" link is missing.  Have you made any other progress on this?  I'm inclined to think it's a Facebook bug, but it seems to have been this way for years...

Comment: I'm using Windows Phone and usually upload pictures from there. Now I wonder why they have "Share" link and none for us!

Comment: funny though after looking some fb docs, you'll notice from their sample screenshots, they also have no "Share" link

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly confident this is a bug.  To encourage Facebook to fix this issue, please "vote" for this bug by adding your app as a "repro" at the following link:

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/154484061346461?browse=search_4f903d2ea60569f93022163

Comment: I have not made any progress on this.